# Is the Moto X 2nd Gen the same as the Moto X Style?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, motorola-droid-x

One of my first questions on this site, please excuse my "noobyness".

I have a predicament which must be overwhelmingly simple for extreme Android Enthusiests to solve.

**Is the Moto X 2nd Gen the same as the Moto X Style?**

I have seen the two names everywhere, and don't know the difference.

http://www.verizonwireless.com/smartphones/moto-x-2nd-gen/?cmp=KNC-C-HQ-NON-R-AC-NONE-NONE-BIN-672702&cmp=KNC-C-HQ-NON-R-AC-NONE-NONE-2K0PX0-PX-GAW-71700000010316665&gclid=CKH4krPU9skCFVCJfgod2ZYJcA&gclsrc=ds

Is this the thing?

Is there a 3rd gen also? I have seen something like a preemium edition. I am really confused, please help.

Thanks,

Ruchir

Answer (score 1):

- Is the Moto X 2nd Gen the same as the Moto X Style?

  **No**

  See the comparison here http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/review/android-smartphones/moto-x-style-vs-moto-x-play-vs-moto-x-2014-3621514/

  Looking at only physical comparison:

  **Moto X (2nd Gen)**: 141x73x10mm, 144g

  **Moto X Style**: 154x76x11mm, 179g
- Is there a 3rd Gen also?

  **Yes**

  On the Motorola website http://www.motorola.in/ clicking on Moto G (3rd Gen) takes you to Moto G (2015) specs whose dimensions are:

  Dimensions
  Height: 142.1mm (5.59 inches)
  Width: 72.4mm (2.85 inches)
  Curve: 6.1-11.6mm (0.24-0.48 inches)

  Weight
  155g (5.47 ounces)

So all three models are different going by external dimensions and weight.

Comment: Is the Style available on Verizon? I cant seem to find it.

Comment: I have no idea. Verizon doesn't operate in my country.  Your question was about similarities/ differences and that has been answered. If you think that answer is adequate, consider "accepting" the solution (by ticking next to answer). That would also help others who refer to this question at a later point of time

Comment: I think this gives a answer http://m.androidcentral.com/how-youll-be-able-buy-moto-x-style-aka-pure-edition